# Magento - Multi Website Setup

Tags: .htaccess, magento-1.7

I am having configuration settings with my multi website magento setup.

I have a website running at abc.com . Now for international storefront I have created another website, store view and store with abc_international as the website code.

In my configuration, I have configured Base URL as abc.com/int/

However, when I access the URL abc.com/int/ it generates a 404 error.

Another important point is even if I specifically make changes in index.php as follows - 
$mageRunCode = "abc_international";
$mageRunType = "website";

Mage::run($mageRunCode, $mageRunType);

Any ideas as to what might be the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to copy index.php and .htaccess files to abc.com/int/ at server and provide particular path to Mage.php file at index.php which is inside abc.com/int/ and in that index.php file you need to modify Mage::run($mageRunCode, $mageRunType); to Mage::run("abc_international", "website"); then it will work if you properly configured multi-website setup.